# Is there any way that I can host .net core API's or .net core web APP on "on premises" server

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-apicontroller

I wanted to host my .net core API in Go Daddy Linux Server and also .net Core Web APP is there any possibility to do that. Also I have seen lots of tutorials to make that happen in Linux server which is for cloud but doesnt work the same scenario for any another on premises server.
If anyone have this experience or can only suggest that if there is possibility for hosting in the go daddy linux server it will be really helpful

Comment: Essentially you should have freedom of choice when it comes to hosting, as asp.net-core (as long as you use Kestrel) comes with a platform-independent webserver. You're not tied to any platform anymore like Asp.Net used to do with IIS. So in the end you could throw it onto any machine you want. Where's the problem with those hosts exactly?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you need to ask them whether they have support .net core on their Linux hosting package. I ever worked with them in the past 8 years ago, I didn't like their support, but I don't know now, maybe they improve better. If you want to use .net core on Linux, Digital Ocean can be good option. I also .net user here but I always use Windows to deploy my .net. From Classic ASP until newest .net core project, I always use Windows Server.